# Lot of spams on drupal 6 site with reCaptcha module

Tags: drupal-6, recaptcha, spam

Anybody know how spammer register the users on drupal 6 site? I used on registration page the reCaptcha module, but spammers register users. In logs I have this message "blocked by CAPTCHA module: challenge "reCAPTCHA" (by module "recaptcha"), user answered "reCAPTCHA", but the solution was "1".", from user/register page, spammer use the brutforce or is bug in reCaptcha module.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have found that spammers manually register.  An unfortunate fact of life that has been discussed [here](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/2943/why-do-i-get-comment-spam-even-with-akismet-and-captcha) before.  The best solution that I have found was to compliment reCaptcha with [Mollem](http://drupal.org/project/mollom).  The results have been much better.

Comment: I used spambot module, work fine